# Windows Credentials Deleted for specific user

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

**UPDATE after further analysis:**
This appears to be caused by tasks scheduled with "Do not store password. The task will only have access to local resources."
[task schedule security options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odhnD.png)

Though, I don't quite understand what this setting is doing? I tried looking for documentation related to it, but unable to locate anything that made sense.

---

I noticed that for a specific user, every time a virtual windows machine is restarted the Generic Credentials under Credential Manager gets deleted. This is not the case for all users on this machine. I almost wonder if there's specific policies that is causing Generic Credentials to be deleted at restart for this user while other users do not have the same policy...

[user with credentials removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9gYa.png)

[another user on same machine, credentials did not get removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebcqh.png)

Has anyone encounter this same issue where only a single user's credentials is getting removed, not everyone on the machine?

Machine is: Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.